# xampp zend framework and zendserver ce one don't get along well in command line

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp, zend-server-ce

i've been using xampp 1.7.3 for a while now and today i've decided to have a look into zend framework and got a zendserver ce 5.0.2.

i'm on windows 7 and until i used the command line tool, i haven't noticed that there was a version of zend framework (zf) shipped with xampp.
zendserver got a more recent version than the xampp one. xampp was already added to the path before zend server.so command prompt is only seeing xampp one, plus it's throwing errors when creating projects.
i'ld like to use the zendserver one as default and i've tried to put the zend server bin before php in the environment variables and restarted the machine but no success.any ideas ? thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot find how to take out the xammp zf path you could always rename/move/delete de version from xammp. Since the zend server one is on your path it should not be a problem at all.

Alternatively you could try replacing the version in xampp with the more recent one. As far as I know xampp does not use zf itself so I doubt it would break something.

If you are just trying out zend any of these solutions is pretty easy to undo. Also maybe look into virtualisation for these kind of needs. Easier to just create virtual machines then make many webservers work on the same one.